# If function to compare 2 two with same texts, different values

Tags: vba, string, if-statement

My two variables, PackageOptions and cell.Value, have the same texts but different values. Is the a way to format them to match so that the code jumps into the if statement? I tried using Trim$ and ascii formatting but don't understand how to format.

String one is type  PackageOptions
String two is type  PackageOptions

[image]

the variable is extracted from the list box:

```
Dim PackageOptions
Dim Customer As String
Dim PreferredDate As String
Dim ServicesLine1 As String
Dim PackageOptions As String
Dim GoogleR As Byte
Dim InvoiceR As Byte

For i = 0 To LbCustomer.ListCount - 1
    If LbCustomer.Selected(i) Then
        Customer = Customer & LbCustomer.List(i) & vbNewLine
        PreferredDate = PreferredDate & LbCustomer.List(i, 1) & vbNewLine
        ServicesLine1 = ServicesLine1 & LbCustomer.List(i, 2) & vbNewLine
        **PackageOptions** = PackageOptions & LbCustomer.List(i, 3) & vbNewLine
        GoogleR = GoogleR & LbCustomer.List(i, 4) & vbNewLine  '
        InvoiceR = InvoiceR & LbCustomer.List(i, 5) & vbNewLine  
    End If
Next i

Dim PrRange As Range
Dim cell As RangeSet PrRange = shPrice.Range("PricingTable[Item]")
Dim ItemRange As Range
Set ItemRange = shPrice.Range("PricingTable[Item Number]")

>looping through a table column, return the row and item number of match
>the variables have different values (shown in images attached)
For Each cell In PrRange
         If PackageOptions = cell.Value Then
         ItemR = cell.Row - shPrice.Range("PricingTable[[#Headers],[Item]]").Row
         ItemNumber = shPrice.Range("PricingTable[Item Number]").Cells(ItemR, 1).Value
         End If

Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite make out what you mean, especially since you don't say which error you get on which line of your code. Perhaps your complaint is just that the comparison doesn't give the result you expect. Anyway, your variable `PackageOptions` is of Variant data type variable holding a string which is exactly what `Cell.Value` should hold, although your supporting screen show it as String.

`PackageOptions = cell.Value` is a very crude but sturdy comparison. Make sure that both items are of the same data type. Use `Cstr(PackageOptions)` to coerce the variant into a string. Perhaps use it on both values, `Cstr(PackageOptions) = Cstr(cell.Value)`.

The StrComp() function allows you more room for adjustment but, as the name promises, it compares two strings. Therefore the outcome will not be any different. The function below will compare text case-insensitive. It will return 0 (zero) if both strings are equal.

```
StrComp(Cstr(PackageOptions), Cstr(cell.Value), VbTextCompare)
```

Comment: @braX thank you so much it worked! I wasn't getting an error in the code, only that the if conditions were not met. This is a great deal help.

Answer (score 0):

The terminating "1310" in the ascii-encoded version of your string `PackageOptions2` represents a Carriage-return+NewLine combination (same as the VBA constant vbCrLf).

It's there because *you added it* when you used

```
PackageOptions = PackageOptions & LbCustomer.List(i, 3) & vbNewLine
```

On Windows `vbNewLine` is the same as `vbCRLf`.  It's not clear why you're adding that - are you collecting multiple values in each of those variables as you loop over the listbox?

Try either not adding `vbNewLine` or something like

```
If Replace(PackageOptions, vbNewLine) = cell.Value Then
```

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you so much @Tim Williams.

Comment: I removed the vbNewLine and the if statement worked. Appreciate the help Tim